# only every other li is being affected by simple mouseover mouseout modal window code

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write simple code that allows specific divs to fadeIn and fadeOut when their corresponding "info divs" are hovered over and out. I have eight list items and eight corresponding "info divs". When the first li is hovered upon, the corresponding "info div" should fade in, and it does. But when I hover over the second li, the third "info div" fades in. The third li affects the fifth, and so on. I have included the jQuery code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.case-info').hide();
        $('#text323-b li').mouseover(function(){
            var x = $(this).index();
            $('.case-info').eq(x).fadeIn();
        });
        $('#text323-b li').mouseout(function(){
            var x = $(this).index();
            $('.case-info').eq(x).fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you show some of your html?

Comment: With very simple markup, your code would work, SO - jQuery version? and show your actual markup for these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take a stab in the dark and assume you have other markup in your LI list like some `<br />` ro some such and this would work that out:

```
$('.case-info').hide();
$('#text323-b li').mouseover(function () {
    var x = $(this).index('#text323-b li');
    $('.case-info').eq(x).fadeIn();
}).mouseout(function () {
    var x = $(this).index('#text323-b li');
    $('.case-info').eq(x).fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you very much! I really appreciate your time to help me with this!